# passing tapped cell data to another view via segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView and I am trying to send the data related to tapped cell to another view via segue. 
My code works only after second tap, and always returning nil at first tap. I suppose for some reason prepareForSegue gets executed first, that's why detailToSend is always nil at the first tap, and with the second tap I get the data from the previous tapped cell. How can I fix this ?
**Updated:**

```
var detailToSend = SingleRepository()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if filteredResult.count > 0 {
        detailToSend = filteredResult[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        detailToSend = finalArrayUnwrapped[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        vc.detail = detailToSend
    }
}
```

My DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UILabel!

var detail: SingleRepository?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let detailUnwrapped = detail {
        print(detailUnwrapped)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure your segue is from the view controller object, and not the cell itself. Also you can avoid the use of the `detailToSend` property by specifying the detail as the `sender` in the `performSegue` call.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see the problem now, I was segueing from the cell and not the view object. problem is solved but I am not sure how to get ride of detailToSend, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have created your segue from the view controller object in the storyboard and not the cell; if you create the segue from the cell, then the segue will fire before `didSelectRowAt` is called.

Once you have set the segue correctly, you can use the `sender` parameter to avoid the use of the `detailToSend` property:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var detailToSend: SingleRepository
    if filteredResult.count > 0 {
        detailToSend = filteredResult[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        detailToSend = finalArrayUnwrapped[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: detailToSend)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? DetailViewController, let detailToSend = sender as? SingleRepository {            
        vc.detail = detailToSend
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and there is an error in the second let you used, are you using Swift 4? because I get  "I get Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer." error on that second let.

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo.  Fixed now

Comment: so far, all the three solutions posted are working fine, but I believe this is the best one for me to use.

Comment: @Paulw11 Like Ali’s scenario I have same situation but differently I have extra table view which has data from detail vc. So my hierarchy like first view data from table view and same data pass to second view’s labels. And finally same data pass to third vc as table view with button click . I am using segues from second vc to third table view. Second vc is child of first vc with navigation. Third vc is child of tabbar and navigation vc. Is it possible with multiple table view and single view as 3 views?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a manual segue in the storyboard and trigger it on tap.
So instead of segueing from a cell to a controller, segue from a controller to another controller.

and then your code will be something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if filteredResult.count > 0 {
        detailToSend = filteredResult[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        detailToSend = finalArrayUnwrapped[indexPath.row]
    }
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

`prepareForSegue` should remain exactly the same.

Also check your `didSelectRowAt` method. You are ignoring everything that happens in scope of

```
if filteredResult.count > 0 {
        detailToSend = filteredResult[indexPath.row]
}
```

because after that you assign

```
detailToSend = finalArrayUnwrapped[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: I had set the manual segue in story board before. I updated the didSelectMethod. the issue now is that with your code after tapping the cell it segue twice, and as before first segue is still nil, but second time gets the objects.

Comment: did you delete the previous cell segue? it might be you have two segues at the same time.

Comment: well, if I delete that then identifier also gets deleted, therefore would not be possible to performSegue.

Comment: if you have a manual segue, just set its identifier to what you want and delete the cell segue

Comment: yeah, you delete this arrow.
Then you ctrl drag from a controller (yellow circle on the top of the controller) to another controller -> select segue type (push) and then click on that arrow and set an identifier

Comment: the issue was that I was not segueing from the view object, and i was doing it from the cell. it is resolved now.